# OpenCv is installed, but module cannot be found, how to make sym-link point to cv2.so file?

Tags: python, linux, opencv, virtualenv, raspbian-stretch

I just followed a tutorial to install virtualenv, and opencv3.3.0 on my raspberry pi, running on raspbian (for robots) 3. The virtualenv is installed properly, and I know that opencv is installed as well because `workon cv` works. However, I am receiving these errors:

```
(cv) pi@dex:~/opencv-3.3.0 $ python
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
>>>
```

From the tutorial, it was suggested that my sym-link does not point to my cv2.so file. I am brand new to Python and I have no clue what a sym-link even is, let alone how to make it point to my cv2.so file.

```
(cv) pi@dex:~/opencv-3.3.0 $ sudo find / -name "cv.py"
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv.py
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
find: ‘/proc/1083/task/1083/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/proc/1083/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/proc/1084/task/1084/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/proc/1084/net’: Invalid argument
(cv) pi@dex:~/opencv-3.3.0 $ sudo find / -name "cv2.so"
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
find: ‘/proc/1083/task/1083/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/proc/1083/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/proc/1084/task/1084/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/proc/1084/net’: Invalid argument
```

Tutorial reference: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/04/raspbian-stretch-install-opencv-3-python-on-your-raspberry-pi/

I would appreciate any help i can get. I have searched all over the internet for a solution or guidance through this problem to no avail. I am brand new to python, and linux so please forgive me if I forgot anything, or  if i am missing something simple and obvious. Thank you for your time.

Comment: `find` shows that `cv` is installed in global Python, not in `virtualenv` . You should first activate `virtualenv` and later install `cv` - ie `pip install opencv-python` or `python -m pip install opencv-python`

Comment: `works cv` starts virtualenv which has name `cv` but it doesn't mean that it has installed `cv`

Comment: this tutorial is 2 years old - current `cv2` has number `'4.1.1'`

Comment: btw: at the end of this year Python 2 ends its life - see [Python 2.7 Countdown](https://pythonclock.org/) - better install and learn Python `3.7` or at least `3.5` (Python `3.8` is very fresh version so better wait few month till all modules will work with this version)

Comment: Well i have python 3.5.3 installed in the virtualenv but i cannot install anything greater or change it outside of the enviornment because for some reason raspbian for robots prohibits it

Comment: so should i delete the opencv in global python? i also installed it in the virtualenv as per the tutorial

Comment: if you don't want to use it with global Python then you can unistall it. Besides, it seams global Python is `2.7`.

Comment: well id like to use it with global python, id like to use it with any python, but it wont work either, do you know what a sym-link is?

Comment: Every Python's version need own installation of all modules. In Python 3.5 you can't use module created for 2.7. Often you can't used even module created for `3.4` or `3.6`. And 64-bit Python 3.5 can't use modules for 32-bit Python 3.5. But using `pip` it should install correct version. In linux you should have command `python`, `python2`, `python2.7`, `python3`, `python3.5` to choose which version you want to use. The same with `pip`, `pip2`, `pip2.7`, `pip3`, `pip3.5`. Or you can use `python -m pip install ...`

Comment: so always first try `pip3.5` or `python3.5 -m pip` to install module for Python 3.5. Usually `pip` is a alias for `pip2.7 but in virtualenv it can be alias for `pip3.5` and you can check it with `pip -V` (the same with `python -V`)

Comment: `sym-link` means "symbolic link" and it is link to file in other folder - like shortcut in Windows but better. Problem with symlink can means that link redirects to not existing file - original file could be deleted or moved.

Comment: Do you know how to get the link to point to the cv2.so file? Should i just delete everything and start over? I dont know what to do and ive spent days trying to figure this out and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: I would uninstall module and install again with `python -m pip install` (after activating virtualenv which you want to use to write code). Different version of modules for different pythons may need different version of file `cv2.so` and addding link manually may not work.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue once when working on linux and this worked for me

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: should i download it in the home directory?

Comment: pip is a package manage system so you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: also, should it be downloaded in the virtualenv? or outside of it? thank you

Comment: reinstalling didnt seem to help :(

Answer (score 0):

You have installed openCV in python2.7 and you're using python3.5! To install it use pip3 instead of pip!

First install pip3 :

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Then install opencv:

```
pip3 install opencv-python --user
```

Comment: It did not work. It says that all of these are already installed

Comment: sudo pip3 install opencv-python --user
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.12.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from opencv-python)